# mongodb shell query with javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a key-value pair in my database which is like this -

```
{ 
  "class" : 
       {
         "name-class" : "working"
         "other-class" : "not working"
        }
}
```

I am trying to run a query with forEach loop which is like below -

```
db.collection.find({ "key" : "value" }).forEach(function(collection) {
    print ( collection.class.name-class );
})
```

I am getting reference error for above. What I understood that it is not able to understand "name-"

I have tried to use escape character as "-", ['name-class'] etc, but nothing is working.

Can you please help me to form a correct query ?

Also, can you please guide, how we can form the query in better way?

Comment: `db.collection.find` returns a Promise, so you may need to resolve the results before attempting your `forEach` function.

Comment: Yes, i was writing the forEach function with the result which was returned by db.collection.find

Comment: in that case, you may need to use `toArray()` to convert your results from the cursor to documents. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/